# change background color of lines in eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse

I have number of python scripts which I am running from eclipse. I need to create a script which will change background color of some lines in eclipse.

Can I do such python script which can change background of some specific lines of code in eclipse?

Comment: Are you using pydev in eclipse? http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/pydev-python-ide-eclipse

Comment: yes i am using pydev. but my question is. i want to make a scrip which will work on my other number of python files and it will change background colors of some lines in those files based on critera in eclipse. can we do that in eclipse? such script which will change it?

Comment: Your question and comments are not clear and confusing. Please edit your question and add some screen shots for easy understanding?